# I'm getting a error of S3StatusErrorMissingSecurityElement on my AWS call

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can't seem to find an additional documentation of this error on AWS and unfortunately I don't have premier support. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you generating the signature for the API call yourself? Is this on an s3 bucket that has encryption enabled on it?

Comment: I'm not generating the signature.   It's a black box and I'm only reading output.  As far as the s3 bucket, I don't have encryption enabled.

Comment: What sdk are you using? Is this the cli? Do you have IAM permissions to do anything in the bucket?